# Javascript and timing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I have a problem with js and timing, which i don't understand

```
project.pro.register_product = function(callback) {
    project.pro.selected.items.push(res.product);
    if( typeof callback === 'function' ) {
        callback();
        project.pro.update_allprice();
        project.audio.play_success();
    };
}

project.pro.update_allprice = function() {
    var a_price = 0.0;
    $.each( project.pro.selected.items, function(i,v) {
        a_price += parseFloat(v['price']); // here i get sometimes a not found error 
    })
}
```

On the last but one line some times i get an error. I thoght, that push runs synchron. What can be my problem?
Any ideas?

Comment: check what is `v` when `v['price']` is undefined

Comment: just because `v` exists doesnt mean it has the member `price`. so i guess price is missing, the rest should always work as far as i can tell from your code. protip: logging is useful for debugging